# Failed to contrast intercepts through emmeans in R

Tags: r, intercept, contrast, emmeans

I would like to test the simetry in the response of an observer to a contrast stimuli with different polarity, positive (white) and negative (black). I took the reaction time (RT) as dependent variable, along four different contrasts. It is known that the response time follows a Pieron curve whose asymptotas are placed (1) at observer threshold (Inf) and (2) at a base RT placed somewere between 250 and 450 msec.
The knowledge allows us to linearize the relationship transforming the independent variable (effective contrast EC) as 1/EC^2 (tEC), so the equation linking RT to EC becomes:

RT = m * tEC + RT0

To test the symmetry I established the criteria: same slope and same intercept in the two polarities implies symmetry.
To obtain the coefficients I made a linear model with interaction (coding trough a dummy variable for Polarity: Positive or Negative). The output of lm is clear to me, but some colegues prefer somthing more similar to an ANOVA output. So I decided to use emmeans to make the contrasts. With the slope is all right, but when computing the interceps starts the problem. The intercepts computed by lm are very different from the output of emmeans, and the conclusions are also different. In what follows I reproduce the example.
The question is two fold: It is possible to use emmeans to solve my problem? If not, it is possible to make the contrasts through other packages (which one)?

#### Data

| RT1000 | EC | tEC | Polarity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 596.3564 | -25 | 0.001600 | Negative |
| 648.2471 | -20 | 0.002500 | Negative |
| 770.7602 | -17 | 0.003460 | Negative |
| 831.2971 | -15 | 0.004444 | Negative |
| 1311.3331 | 15 | 0.004444 | Positive |
| 1173.8942 | 17 | 0.003460 | Positive |
| 1113.7240 | 20 | 0.002500 | Positive |
| 869.3635 | 25 | 0.001600 | Positive |

#### Code

```
# Model
model <- lm(RT1000 ~ tEC * Polarity, data = Data)

# emmeans
library(emmeans)
# Slopes
m.slopes <- lstrends(model, "Polarity", var="tEC")
# Intercepts
m.intercept <- lsmeans(model, "Polarity")

# Contrasts
pairs(m.slopes)
pairs(m.intercept)
```

#### Outputs

Modelo

| term | estimate | std.error | statistic | p.value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 449.948 | 66.829 | 6.733 | 0.003 |
| tEC | 87205.179 | 20992.976 | 4.154 | 0.014 |
| PolarityPositive | 230.946 | 94.511 | 2.444 | 0.071 |
| tEC:PolarityPositive | 58133.172 | 29688.551 | 1.958 | 0.122 |

Slopes (it is all right)

| Polarity | tEC.trend | SE | df | lower.CL | upper.CL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Negative | 87205.18 | 20992.98 | 4 | 28919.33 | 145491.0 |
| Positive | 145338.35 | 20992.98 | 4 | 87052.51 | 203624.2 |

| contrast | estimate | SE | df | t.ratio | p.value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Negative - Positive | -58133.17 | 29688.55 | 4 | -1.958101 | 0.12182 |

Intercepts (problem)

| Polarity | lsmean | SE | df | lower.CL | upper.CL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Negative | 711.6652 | 22.2867 | 4 | 649.7874 | 773.543 |
| Positive | 1117.0787 | 22.2867 | 4 | 1055.2009 | 1178.957 |

| contrast | estimate | SE | df | t.ratio | p.value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Negative - Positive | -405.4135 | 31.51816 | 4 | -12.86285 | 0.000211 |

Computed intercepts through emmeans differs from the ones computed by lm. I think the problem is that the model is not defined for EC = 0. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are calling the intercepts are not; they are the model predictions at the mean value of `tEC`. If you want the intercepts, use instead:

```
m.intercept <- lsmeans(model, "Polarity", at = list(tEC = 0))
```

You can tell what reference levels are being used via

```
ref_grid(model)     # or   str(m.intercept)
```

Please note that the model fitted here consists of two lines with different slopes; hence the difference between the predictions changes depending on the value of `tEC`. Thus, I would strongly recommend *against* testing the comparison of the intercepts; those are predictions at a `tEC` value that, as you say, can't even occur. Instead, try to be less of a mathematician and do the comparisons at a few representative values of `tEC`, e.g.,

```
LSMs <- lsmeans(model, "Polarity", at = list(tEC = c(0.001, 0.003, 0.005)))
pairs(LSMs, by = tEC)
```

You can also easily visualize the fitted lines:

```
emmip(model, Polarity ~ tEC, cov.reduce = range)
```

Comment: Thanks Russ. Before submitting the question I read a lot of your posts. Really informative.... but I did not manage to solve the problem. In the present case the intercept at 0 has a precise meaning, because is the base RT. The others points, as you suggest, could be more problematic.

Comment: If my answer helped, I'd appreciate your accepting it.